# passwordless scp without keys

Tags: ssh, scp, ssh-keys, rsa, private-key

I am looking for some option that will allow me to accept files from any server using SCP command. I am aware of the process of creating password-less logins. But what I am looking for is an option on central server that can be changed to accept files from anonymous users.
This may look like security hazard, but that is exactly what I am asked to do.

Comment: Check if this covers your question: http://serverfault.com/questions/70657/ssh-access-without-password

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is doable.

sshd_config:

```
UsePAM no
PermitEmptyPasswords yes
```

delete password from the user:

```
passwd -d user
```

Comment: This lets them do more than accept files though. For example, anyone can see the list of uploaded files, download a file someone else uploaded,  corrupt a file someone else uploaded, and so on.

Comment: Right, I assumed the author of the question was aware of the security implications. A user can also log on the machine and show processes, execute commands...
Scponly can be used to restrict the user to file transferts only.